# Updating innerHTML value changes the cursor position to starting point

Tags: angular, innerhtml

HTML:

```
<h1 contenteditable="true" [innerHTML]="myData['name']" (click) = "myFunc($event)"></h1>
```

TS:

```
myData = {name: "test"};

myFunc ($event) {
     changedVal = $event.target.innerHTML;
     myData['name'] = changedVal; //this will update the innerHTML of h1
}
```

While editing the editable h1 element value, every time cursor is moving to the starting point

Comment: Can you explain in detail? not able to understand what do you want to enhance.

Comment: Maybe you should call the function `onblur`?

Comment: i'm changing the json data dynamically while editing the h1 element.